# Использование метода для изменения переменных

Tags: java, массивы, методы

Есть проблема: на днях учитель по компьютерам обмолвился о том, что можно использовать метод с меткой `void` для изменения переменных. Привёл рабочий пример:

```
import java.util.*;

class training
{
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int [] a = new int [10];
        firstnum(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    static void firstnum (int[] t)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < t.length; i++)
        t[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
    }
}
```

Код рабочий. Выводит заполненный массив целых чисел. Обратите внимание: метод в котором заполняется массив имеет метку `void`, то есть не возвращает никакие значение но, почему то, заполняет массив.

Случай второй. Пытался сделать такое же с обычным целым числом. Код:

```
import java.util.*;

class training2
{
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int a = 0;
        firstnum(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    static void firstnum (int t)
    {
        t = 1;
    }
}
```

Выводит `0`. Почему и как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: массив заполняется по ссылке в первом случае, больше информации в книге _Философия Java (Инициализация массивов)_

Comment: Очень печально, что ваш  учитель-по-компьютерам лишь "обмолвился", ибо из-за вот таких вот обмолвок JMM часто стреляет в колено.

Comment: @0xFFh Что такое JMM?

Comment: Вообще-то это **не дубликат** вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/267073/Передача-по-значению-в-java. Там вопрос не про передачу параметров, а про присваивание новых значений immutable-объектам, а заголовок там неправильный.

Answer (score 9):

В Java все параметры передаются при вызове по значению (*pass by value*), однако передача примитивных и объектных типов несколько различается. Из-за этого различия, [некоторые](http://www.quizful.net/interview/java/passing-parameters-reference-value) **ошибочно** говорят, что объекты в Java передаются при вызове по ссылке – и это принципиально неверно, так как при передаче объектов в Java передается не **сама ссылка** на объект, а **копия этой ссылки**.

При передаче примитивного типа происходит копирование значения в локальную переменную метода, соответственно, изменение этого значения в методе никак не повлияет на значение переменной вне метода.

При передаче объектного типа (а массив в Java [является объектом](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)) происходит копирование **ссылки** на этот объект в локальную переменную метода, соответственно, изменение **состояния** переданного объекта будет видно вне метода.

Стоит обратить внимание на передачу неизменяемых (*immutable*) объектов (например объектов типа `String` и всех оболочек примитивов: `Integer`, `Float` и т.д.): при изменении таких объектов **создается новый объект**, поэтому эти изменения извне видны не будут.

Касательно Ваших примеров:

В первом случае передается объект `int[] t`, соответственно, изменение его состояния будет видно извне.

Во втором случае передается примитив `int t`, соответственно, изменение значения этой переменной в методе не видно извне.

---

Есть еще такой термин: вызов по соиспользованию (*call by sharing*) – по сути, объекты в Java передаются именно так, но в данном контексте вызов по соиспользованию можно назвать некоторой разновидностью вызова по значению, поэтому в общем можно сказать, что в Java все параметры передаются при вызове по значению.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понятно!

Answer (score 2):

В этом нет никакой мистики, и тип метода - `void` или какой-то другой - к вопросу не имеет никакого отношения. Все дело в том, как в метод передаются параметры. Параметры примитивных типов (`int`, `double` и т. п.) передаются по значению - иными словами, при вызове метода создается неявная локальная (существующая только внутри этого метода) переменная, куда копируется значение, переданное в параметре. Недаром же это именно **значение**, например, это может быть значение выражения `5 + 10`. Метод может делать со своим параметром что угодно - меняться будет только переменная, существующая внутри метода, никакие переменные в окружающем мире никак не изменятся. Вы же не ждете, что при вызове `firstnum(5 + 10)` пять превратиться в 10 или 10 в 20?

Другое дело - параметры объектных типов, к которым относятся и массивы. В этом случае в метод фактически передается ссылка на объект, и когда метод выполняет какие-то манипуляции с таким объектом, меняется сам исходный объект. В вашем первом примере параметр `t` фактически является ссылкой на массив `a`, описанный вне метода, и когда метод меняет значения элементов массива - это меняются элементы массива `a`. Это важно понимать и учитывать, иначе можно получить совсем не тот результат, который надо.

При это также надо помнить, что неизменяемые объекты (immutable), напр. `String`, а также объекты-оболочки (типа `Integer`, `Double` и т. п.) при передаче их в качестве параметров ведут себя в некотором смысле не как объекты, а как примитивные типы - хотя в метод передается ссылка на исходный объект, но при присваивании такому параметру нового значения внутри метода фактически создается новый объект с новым значением, и локальной переменной внутри метода присваивается ссылка на этот новый объект, а при завершении работы метода такой объект просто уничтожается. Исходный объект, ссылка на который был передан методу, при этом никак не меняется. Внешне это выглядит так, как при работе с примитивными типами - исходная переменная вне метода не меняется, что бы метод не делал со своими параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо потому, что массив (хоть и тип `int`) делает автоупаковку (попробовать почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583927/)) в `Integer[]`, а `Integer` — это объект. Ну собсн объект передается по ссылке (кто-то скажет, что в Java все передается по значению и там статьи в инете всякие, но, не будем вдаваться в детали). И поэтому меняется.

А не массив, простой примитив не распаковывается. Поэтому ничего и не меняется.

Comment: А в какой момент, по Вашему мнению, происходит автоупаковка? И, самое главное, зачем?

Comment: Быть честным, ничего не понял из написанного [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583927/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-boxing-unboxing-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC). Но это не так важно. Мне просто надо знать с какими типами переменных будет  работать.

Comment: Массив(не переменная но надо было включить) - да, int - нет. Float, double, String, boolean?

Comment: @АлексейШвачко, быть честным, ничего не понял из вашей реплики. Что вы хотели сказать?

Comment: @m. vokhm Уже не важно. Я получил ответ.

Comment: Тут дело не в автоупаковке. Массив сам по себе - объект, и фактически передается ссылка на него. Его элементы при передаче никак не меняются, int не упаковывается в Intger. Физически это та же область памяти остается.