# Изменения Node в Java внутри метода

Tags: java, методы, объекты

Решил написать простейший метод - опустошить узел.

```
public static void Node <Integer> n1 (Node <Integer> n1)
{
 while (n1 != null)
    n1 = n1.getNext();
}
```

Обнаружил что узел не изменился. Перенёс цикл в главный метод - работает.

Вопрос таков: почему узел не изменился внутри метода, узел ведь объект? Почему стеки, очереди, массивы и другие объекты изменяются внутри методов `void`, а узел нет?

UPD: этот метод который изменяет добавляет в узел цепь в конец узла работает.

```
public static void what (Node <Integer> n1, int a)
{
while (n1.hasNext())
   n1 = n1.getNext();
Node <Integer> n7 = new Node <Integer> (a);
n1.setNext(n7);
}
```

Comment: связанные вопросы: [Использование метода для изменения переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612657/227016) и [Передача по значению в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/267073/227016)

Comment: @diraria обновил вопрос и прочитал эти темы. Всё ещё не понимаю посему первый метод не изменяет узел а второй исправно выполняет свою задачу.

Comment: Вы можете в пределах метода изменить поля объекта, переданного по ссылке в качестве аргумента. Однако, если вы измените саму ссылку на объект - никакого результата не будет. Просто возвращайте из метода обновлённую ссылку, если хотите.

Comment: @AlexChermenin что? Я не очень понимаю о чём вы говорите. Ссылка на объект? Я думал что в Java нет указателей o_0

Comment: @AlexShvachko возможно не совсем корректно выразился - да, все параметры в Java передаются по значению, но таким значением для ссылочного типа является сама ссылка на объект в памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не до конца поняли как это работает.
В метод передается **ссылка** на объект, пусть это будет ссылка, которая смотрит на объект `n1`: `A -> n1`

Когда вы в своем методе выполняете операцию присваивания `n1 = n1.getNext();` ваша ссылка будет смотреть на следующий `Node`, `A -> n1.getNext()`, при этом сам `Node` `n1` не изменится, а вы хотите изменить именно его.
Вот вам пример:

```
public void example(){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    wrongChangeList(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    correctChangeList(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}

private void correctChangeList(List<Integer> list){
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30));
}

private void wrongChangeList(List<Integer> list){
    list = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30);
}
```

> [1, 2, 3]
>
> [10, 20, 30]

При вызове `wrongChangeList` ваш внешний список не изменится, изменится лишь **ссылка** внутри метода `wrongChangeList`
Во втором случае мы изменяем непосредственно объект.

Надеюсь, вы сможете на основе этого понять, как работает ваш второй метод и почему не работает первый.

Comment: Я всё понял. Благодарю за помощь.