# Методы с переменным числом аргументов в Java

Tags: java, методы, variable

Не пойму, почему работает следующий код:

```
public class Runner {
    public static void printArgCount(Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Object args: " + args.length);
    }
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        printArgCount(5, 7); // вывод Object args: 2
    } 
}
```

Мы передаем в метод несколько примитивных значений типа int, но срабатывает метод, который на вход принимает несколько сложных типов. Почему так?

Comment: [Что такое упаковка и распаковка(boxing/unboxing)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583927/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0boxing-unboxing)

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах метода `printArgCount(5, 7)` числа 5 и 7 неявно преобразуются в объекты типа Integer, т.к. в Java для примитивных типов данных существуют их классы-обертки. Как мы помним, все классы в Java унаследованы от базового класса `Object`.