# Почему кэш на основе HashMap<Float, Object> забивает память?

Tags: kotlin, кэширование, hashmap

Использую кэш на основе HashMap<Float, Object>.

get вызывается каждый тик программы и почему-то в таком случае за секунду память переваливает за 100мб.

Однако если использовать в качестве ключа Int, то всё нормально.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: скорей всего это связано с [boxing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583927/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0boxing-unboxing). У Integer есть пул в диапазоне -128..127 и похоже инты у вас по большей части попадают в этот пул

Comment: @IR42 Вы правы, при использовании ключа > 127 появляется эта проблема. Довольно странно... Неужели kotlin или java превращает примитив в объект? Зачем? Чтобы вычислить хэш?

Comment: потому что примитивы - не объекты, а дженерик коллекции могут хранить только объекты. [Why can Java Collections not directly store Primitives types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types). Если требуется производительность и более адекватное потребление памяти, то можно найти библиотеку, в которой реализована хэш таблица с ключом-примитивом нужного типа и использовать данный класс